# Django From Choices Tuple Concatnation

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to do something like this in my form:

```
sites = list( Site.objects.all().order_by('site_code') )
sites = ((s.site_code, s.site_code) for s in sites )
SITE_CHOICES = ('All', 'All') + (sites,)
```

I know that I can't really concatenate two tuples, and what it does it makes a new reference of tuple, but the error that I am getting is

```
object.__new__(generator) is not safe, use generator.__new__()
```

I've tried different things like trying to add the tuple directly in my comprehension, etc but no luck.  Anybody have a better solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: I also tried it as a list but I get the same error

Comment: Is this the django site object? If so, what is `site_code` ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that, it's my custom class (model)

Comment: Are you placing this in settings.py? That script runs before a connection is set up. Also, post the error please. And moreover you _can_ concatenate tuples (can't modify them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using lists instead of tuples?

```
sites = [(s.site_code, s.site_code) for s in Site.objects.all().order_by('site_code')]
SITE_CHOICES = [('All', 'All')] + sites
```

Hope that helps.